# Creating and joining a multiplayer game over a LAN

Tags: networking, multiplayer, udk

I'm trying to create and join a multiplayer game that has been created from a custom UDK installation.

It works correctly when two (or more) instances of the game are created on the same computer and are connected over localhost by running the following commands:

```
udk.exe server map_name
udk.exe 127.0.0.1
```

The problem comes when trying to connect to the game server over a LAN (with the command `udk.exe server_ip_address`); the clients are unable to connect and the default map is loaded. The server log reports a client disconnection from the computer trying to connect. The client log reports the error, `Error: Can't start an online game that hasn't been created`.

Both computers are able to ping each other, as well as both having their firewalls disabled. Many combinations of the command-line arguments for starting the server have been tried. Creating an installer from the server machine and installing a fresh copy of the game on the client has also been tried.

Any solutions on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the server bound to the correct interface? If it works locally its possible its just binding to the localhost/loopback interface. Then again I have no idea about the UDK.

Comment: Have you tried: `udk.exe server map_name?lan` (or `?bIsLanMatch=true`)

Comment: @Phillip, yes I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the correct answer, thanks to this thread on Epic's forum: http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/735202-Multiplayer-testing-problems-Solved

In order to play a networked game, the following files need to be identical on every client and also the server.

- GameUniqueID in Binaries\UnSetup.Game.xml
- UDKGame\Script\*
- UDKGame\Content\*
- UDKGame\Config\*